# Javascript - Google api refresh event

Tags: google-maps, load, refresh

Im doing a php web, that refresh its content with ajax and map is refreshed calling with a timer the load() function of the map.. thats no problem

My problem is, i have to put a map.setCenter first time. Imagine i start to search a marker i put in the map, and then after 20 seconds it reloads the map and it is going again to my "setCenter".. i dont want that. I want to refresh but the map STAYS where i am searching...

is there any function for doing that? here is my load function

```
function load() {
      if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
        var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
        map.addControl(new GSmallMapControl());
        map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());
        map.setCenter(new GLatLng(-34.603365,-58.379416),11);   
        map.enableScrollWheelZoom();


        GDownloadUrl("creoXml.php", function(data) {
          var xml = GXml.parse(data);
          var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
          for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            var name = markers[i].getAttribute("numMovil");
            var type = "Movil";
            var nameTit = "Móvil "+name;
            var point = new GLatLng(parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("latitud")),
                                    parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("longitud")));
            var marker = createMarker(point, nameTit,type);
            map.addOverlay(marker);
          }
        });
      }
    }




    function createMarker(point, name,type) {
      var marker = new GMarker(point, customIcons[type]);
      var html = "<b>" + name + "</b>";
      GEvent.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        marker.openInfoWindowHtml(html);
      });
      return marker;
    }
```

look that everytime i call load(), my setCenter is that.. and if i remove the setCenter with a condition, the map turns into white..   thanks

Answer (score 0):

Put a global variable in you code and call it loading=1.Then in your load function put something like this

```
if(loading==1){
  setCenter....
  loading=0;
}
```